# Problems with rigid body rope

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, rigid-body-simulation, geometry

I have created a a rope, using the "path" curve and rigid body simulation, like in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/Lg7jxAMs60Q

But I was faced with two problems:

1. During simulation, the rope becomes wider at one side and narrow on the other.
2. The rope slightly passes through the collision object.

As I understand, the second problem appears, because I have not applied the "Bevel object" to the curve. Is there a way to set the distance between the rope and the collision object, without turning curve into a mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried that tutorial now, but in the tut it uses softbodies, not rigidbodies! I didn't "apply bevel"  or convert the rope to mesh, and it works well to me. That said:

1. I dont' get the wider side, during simulation, there must be something that you did differently, perhaps?
2. If you want to avoid that, you can try to just increase the "outer" softbody collision to the cylinder, I get good results with around 0.05 (default was 0.02 and with that I could "see" the rope inside the cylinder).

Comment: 1. Soft body, of course, my typo. Ok, I'll try to remake again.
2. Yes, this is what I was looking for, thank you!